# TVHeadend with DD - Max SX8 Basic 8xDVB-S2 Unicable - scan works, but no stream?

Tags: debian

I have a strange problem related to tvheadend on a Debian Server Machine with 2 Digital-Devices Max SX8 Basic PCIe 8xDVB-S2 Tuner Cards.
In general, I am extremely familiar with tvheadend, I have ~15 working setups - and I kind of triple checked everything already, so I assume it`s nothing really simple.

TVHeadend - Version : 4.3-2027
Setup :
Sat-LNB directed to Astra 19.2E - DUR-line UK 124-3L - 24x Unicable +3X Legacy - dCSS LNB
It is a unicable LNB supporting Unicable1/2 (Jess) with 24 participants. Unicable LNB-port is connected with a unicable-supporting 2x-splitter to each of the upper F-ports of the tuner cards, as described by digital-devices. LNB-Power is inserted using a unicable power inserter with separate powersupply.

Driver:
Current git version installed exactly as described in digital-devices docs. Tuners are showing up in tvheadend as expected (in fmode=0 - 4 tuners per card, in fmode=3 8 tuners).

TVHeadend - Unicable config :
Tested multiple configs, see problem-description.

System-Log:

- all info stated as expected in the logs (related to driver init, ddbridge module config param "fmode" is set to 3 for unicable - and is being stated in the log as being set)

Problem:

While I have successfully tested both cards in "normal" mode (fmode=0), having each connected one tuner to a legacy port including all functions (scan, streaming)

- but in unicable mode, I can do a successful scan, but any stream I try to start, doesnt open, and for Input/Output on Status>Subscriptions-Tab I get extremely low values (any channel, sd or hd, non-scrambled services).

What I already found out so far - frequencies & ids for unicable "seem" to be right to me, as in any other combinations (id/freq, id counting from 0 or 1 for first channel  of the lnb) scan does not work any more.

Signal strenght for the channel is being shown with the same values as with the (successful) test using fmode=0 and the legacy lnb port (~15dB).

What I could not find out yet : Correct Pin setting for the LNB - as the LNB states none - I assume it`s "No Pin" ... Any tests made no difference.

Does anybody by any means have an idea where that behaviour (scan successful, but no stream) could come from?

Thanks a bunch,
Oliver

Comment: Hi Oliver, did you ever manage to get it to work? I'm experiencing similar problems with my recently purchased MAX SX8 Pro. I started using fmode=3 from the get-go but streaming wouldn't work, I then switched to fmode=0 and streaming started working as expected (I still see 8 DVB devices under /dev/dvb though) not sure if there's anything else that needs to be configured within tvheadend to make it work.